# Instantiating objects

Tags: c#, .net

This may be a dumb question although due to my poor wording i'm having a hard time getting a good understanding from searching up on it. When instantiating an object why is the declared like so.

```
Object @object = new Object();
// rather than just
Object @object;
```

Is this simply just to call the objects constructor or is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Because until you give it an instance of a class it is only a null shaped version of the class.

Comment: Think of the `@object` variable as a post-it note, and `Object` as a house. This: `Object @object;` only gives you a blank post-it note. This: `new Object()` builds a house, and this: `... = ...` assigns the address of the house to the post-it note, which gives you a post-it note with an address on it. So your first statement constructs the object, declares the variable, and assigns the address of the object (the reference to it) to the variable. Your second statement only declares a variable, as of yet it has no value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because thats the syntax to make it a new instance.

Comment: Static classes *can* have constructors... At least a single one without any parameters.

Comment: Also, a static class isn't an implementation of a singleton pattern. Why there is some similarity it is not the same thing.

Comment: If you kept the first sentence, but removed the following three, then I'd say you nailed this answer.

Comment: Points taken on board.